# String reversing in C not working

Tags: c, string

I tried to reverse a string using c but the following snippet is not working and the output is not printed as expected,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(const char * orig);

int main(void)
{
    char * string = "REVERSE";
    reverse(string);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(const char * orig)
{
    int i = 0, j=strlen(orig);
    int k = j;
    printf("The string is : %s \n",orig);
    char * new =  (char *)malloc((j*sizeof(char))+1);
    while(j > 0)
    {
        new[i++] = orig[j--];
    }
    new[k+1] = '\0';

    printf("\n The Reversed string is : %s",new);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**:

is that at the first iteration `orig[j=strlen(orig)`]`  is the string terminator. You are placing the terminator at the beginning of the new string.

Change to

```
new[i++] = orig[--j];
```

[live](https://ideone.com/daUVAp)

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop `while (j > 0)`, `j` is `strlen(orig)`, thus `orig[j--]` is the string terminating `'\0'`.

With `new[i++] = orig[j--];` where `i == 0`, the first character of `new` indicated the end of string, and thus the resulting string is always empty.

You may want to change it into `new[i++] = orig[--j];`.

You also need to change `new[k+1] = '\0';` into `new[k] = '\0';` to terminate the output string `new` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Algorithmic errors

- `j` should start at `strlen(orig)-1`, otherwise you are copying the string terminator in the first position of `new`, thus making it a zero-length string;
- the loop condition should read `j>=0` - you do want to copy the first character of the target string;
- you must manually terminate `new` with a NUL character;

#### Language usage errors

- you are `malloc`ing but not `free`ing - thus your `reverse` function is leaking memory;
- the conversion from string literal to non-`const` `char *` (in `main`) is deprecated;

#### Stylistic warnings

- `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so it's useless to include it in the calculation;
- although a valid variable name in C, `new` is a reserved keyword in C++, so you may want to use a different name (often C code ends up mixed in C++ code and/or editors use the same highlighter definition thus confusing matters).